# NSString Class - Sample Code Online

Tags: objective-c, class, nsstring

Lets say I just want to NSLog a string - can someone explain the difference between:
Code 1:

```
NSString *testString;  
testString = [[NSString alloc] init];  
testString = @"Here's a test string in testString!";  
NSLog(@"testString: %@", testString);
```

and Code 2:

```
NSString *testString = @"Here's a test string in testString!";
NSLog(testString)
```

Let's assume I am using ARC.
Thanks

Comment: The second way is like doing *[[NSString alloc]initWithString: @"Here's a test string in testString!"]*, except that since the string is literal and known at compile time, some optimizations may be made and the retain count (under ARC you can see it with *CFGetRetainCount*) is undefined. So this makes you understand that in the first case the first message pair alloc+init is useless. More details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775956/authoritative-description-of-objectivec-string-literals

Comment: Another victim of the rather awful tutsplus tutorial, it seems.

Comment: @bbum I am already fairly fluent in Obj-C, but not so much memory management so was just skim reading that to refresh my memory and it surprised me.  What comprehensive online tutorial would you recommend instead?

Comment: If you are fluent in Objective-C, then you know how broken that code is?  `testString = [[NSString alloc] init];` followed by an assignment to `testString` is completely meaningless.   As far as recommendations?  I always start with Apple's documentation and examples and go from there.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this might not be what you're asking, but the second example is a bad practice. The compiler wants a string literal for `NSLog`. It's not required, but prevents a potential security problem (as per the warning). The first argument is interpreted with the `printf` formatter. If you do not use a string literal for your format (first argument) and the string is user-inputted that user could crash your application by passing invalid format data.

You can read about the vulnerability here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format_string_attack

You can rewrite 'Code 2' to avoid this problem like this:

```
NSString *testString = @"Here's a test string in testString!";
NSLog(@"%@", testString);
```

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", testString) => NSLog(@"%@", testString);

Comment: @Grady Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 3):

Code 1:

You're creating and then throwing away an empty `NSString`. Then using a format string to log a string literal.

Code 2:

You're directly trying to log a string literal (via a variable).

Your ideal code is a combination of both where you don't create the unused string and you use a format string while logging.